# About the android app which is used for download the image but not working properly

Tags: java, android

My application is for downloading the image by just clicking a button.when i run the project it shows no errors.Even directory and folder is also created in external storage in which image should be saved but the size of the downloaded image is 0.0MB. i could not find the reason.

here is my main_activity.class file

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView t1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        t1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);
        Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.click);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startDownload();
            }
        });

    }
    public void startDownload(){
        String url="http://p1.pichost.me/i/42/1651529.jpg";
        new DownloadFile(MainActivity.this).execute(url);
    }
}
```

here is my DownloadFile.class

```
public class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {
    Context context;
    public DownloadFile(Context context) {
        super();
        this.context=context;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {

            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            HttpURLConnection connection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.connect();
            File rootDirectory=new File(
                    Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),"my dream");
            if(!rootDirectory.exists()){
                rootDirectory.mkdirs();
            }
            File file=new File(rootDirectory,"nish_img.png");
            file.createNewFile();
            InputStream input=connection.getInputStream();
            FileOutputStream output=new FileOutputStream(file);
            byte buffer[]=new byte[1024];
            int count=0,total=0;
            while((count=input.read())>0) {
                total += count;
                output.write(buffer, 0, count);
            }
            if(total==0){
                Toast.makeText(context,"not completed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();
            Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
            intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(file));
            context.sendBroadcast(intent);

        }catch (Exception e){}
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        Toast.makeText(context,"on starting",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        Toast.makeText(context,"completed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

here is my AndroidMenifest.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.nishtha.service_exp">


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

</manifest>
```

here is my activity_main.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="not downloaded"
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="click to download"
        android:id="@+id/click"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Can any one please fine the error in this code??it drives me literally crazy and it is deprecated code what is new method to download files. please give me some good stuff to understand this.

Comment: here: `while((count=input.read())>0) {`

Comment: can you explain the answer in detail?? i m not able to understand

Comment: don't you see that you are not puting anything in `buffer`?